# Bitbucket Pipeline trying to get list of files changed compared to

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following bash script I use to perform linting checks in a bitbucket pipeline.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master
FORK_POINT=$(git merge-base HEAD origin/master)
PY_FILES=$(git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD $FORK_POINT | grep "\.py$")

if [ "$PY_FILES" ]; then
    flake8 $PY_FILES
else
    echo "No *.py files found"
    exit 0
 fi
```

This was working fine up until December 4th around 4pm UTC. After some experimenting, I have narrowed the problem down to this line
`PY_FILES=$(git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD $FORK_POINT | grep "py$")`. When I remove the grep and `echo $PY_FILES` the script completes successfully but nothing shows up in the log. So, it appears that `git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD $FORK_POINT` isn't returning anything when run by the pipeline, which I guess causes grep to error? When I run this locally it is all fine, so `git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD $FORK_POINT` should definitely be returning results.

Can anyone help me find out what went wrong here, or advise me on another way I can get a list of python files changed in a branch to run flake8 on?

Comment: to further debug, have your pipeline output the values it has at hand : print the sha1 for HEAD, origin/master and FORK_POINT : `git rev-parse HEAD`, `git rev-parse origin/master`, `echo $FORK_POINT`. Chances are they do not match what you expect.

Comment: @FurtherReading It would be helpful to have the final full solution as the accepted answer rather than the trouble shooting questions as the accepted answer.

Comment: I never got a final solution. The issue only occurred in one repo and I never reproduced it. ~it is a mystery~ but the accepted answer is a good start to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply need to debug your pipeline ; one obvious difference between your local clone and the one used by bitbucket pipeline is that you are very probably not working on the same active commit (`HEAD`).

Have your pipeline output what it is working with :

- its active commit : `git rev-parse HEAD`
- its version of `origin/master` : `git rev-parse origin/master`
- the reuslt of `git merge-base` : `echo $FORK_POINT`

---

From your comments : an empty `FORK_POINT` could indicate that the pipeline was trigered from a commit which hasn't a common ancestor with `origin/master` anymore.

Check the history of the remote `HEAD` :

```
git log --graph --oneline <sha from the pipeline>
```

You can for example compare it to the history of `origin/master` :

```
git log --graph --oneline <sha> origin/master
```

Comment: Had a look at these logs. `git rev-parse HEAD` locally gives the hash of the last common ancestor, but on the pipeline it gives the hash of like 2 or 3 commits previous. When you say that i might be working on different commits - I am editing the file here then commiting and pushing it direct to bitbucket, so shouldn't that mean that the commits should be the same?

Comment: the answer lies on how the pipeline is executed : what are the trigger condiftions ? what actions does the pipeline run before executing the code in your script ? that kind of debugging

Comment: It triggers when I push a commit. It runs `pip install flake8==3.8.4` and then the bash. None of that should change the commit right?

Comment: Well : obviously it doesn't checkout the correct commit (not the one you expect at least). You can probably see many of the parameters of the pipeline in the environment when your script is run. The most direct (but verbose) way to view the environement is to add `env | sort` in your script, it could output credentials to things you wouldn't like to store in a persistent log though. Check bitbucket's doc to view what environment variables are useful.

Comment: Note that : `flake8` will run whatever the list of python files you feed him. If the HEAD is wrong, you are probably not scanning the files you should ...

Comment: The Build setup logs show it is checking out the right commit. Adding echos to confirm in the bash show it is correct as well. The only odd thing is `git merge-base HEAD origin/master` fails on the pipeline but doesn't locally. Luckily though `git rev-parse HEAD` gets what I need to get the list. The only mystery is why `git merge-base HEAD origin/master` suddenly started failing.

Comment: Ah, does your pipeline use sparse checkouts ? or turned on sparse checkouts by default ? If the clone inspected by the script does not have the complete history of your HEAD commit, `git merge-base` could fail